# Accessing elements by letter inside templated math vector structure

Tags: c++

I have a `Vector3` structure that I define using a union, such that I can access individual elements by both a variable and array:

```
 struct Vector3 {
     union {
         struct {
             float x;
             float y;
             float z;
         };
         struct {
             float arr[3];
         };
     };
 };
```

I would like to generalize `Vector2`, `Vector3`, `Vector4` structures using a templated struct like this:

```
 template<typename T, int size>
 struct Vector {
     float arr[size];
 };
```

However I would like to preserve the convenience of accessing individual elements by variable. For `Vector2` I would like to have variables `x,y`. For `Vector4` `x,y,z,w`.

While one could definitely do away with the variables, and instead access the elements of an array like this:

```
 float Vector<T>::x() {
     return arr[0]; 
 }
```

However this is unfortunately not a viable approach for me. I can't do away with how much more readable the code is by using variables than functions.

Edit: I'm editing the question instead of seeking a way to utilize unions. I would like to instead ask if there's any other way to access elements like this `vec.x`, `vec.y`, `vec.z`, in a templated implementation of the above mentioned vector structure?

Comment: fyi anonymous `struct`s are not part of the C++ Standard.  Using a `union` to access the non-active member is Undefined Behaviour (some compilers allow this as an extension - you need to check).

Comment: don't focus on syntax. You can always fall back to macro voodo to enable any syntax. Anyhow, what is a viable approach for you? You want to be able to write `some_vector.x = 3;`, right?

Comment: @RichardCritten To my knowledge this (using unions) is an implementation used in the popular glm library. Not sure why they use it if it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes that's right. Are you suggesting using macros?

Comment: Why not define it clearly with `std::array<float, Size>`, then have a template specialisation for whatever size you want to provide easy accessors for.

Comment: @M.A Yes I could definitely do that :). The question remains though.

Comment: @LennyWhite _"...It's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written..."_ source https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union  and I suspect glm is a C library and in C it's ok to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do away with unions and C style arrays.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:25,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:25,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ccassert%3E%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cclass+TFloat,+std::size_t+Size%3E%0Astruct+Vector%0A%7B%0A++++std::array%3CTFloat,+Size%3E+array%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Cclass+TFloat%3E%0Astruct+Vector%3CTFloat,+3%3E%0A%7B%0A++++std::array%3CTFloat,+3%3E+array%3B%0A%0A++++const+TFloat%26+x+%3D+array%5B0%5D%3B%0A++++const+TFloat%26+y+%3D+array%5B1%5D%3B%0A++++const+TFloat%26+z+%3D+array%5B2%5D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Vector%3Cfloat,+3%3E+myArr+%3D+%7B1,2,3%7D%3B%0A++++assert((myArr.x+%2B+myArr.y)+%3D%3D+3)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:38.54574501870335,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:61.45425498129665,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <array>

template <class TFloat, std::size_t Size>
struct Vector
{
    std::array<TFloat, Size> array;
};

template<class TFloat>
struct Vector<TFloat, 3>
{
    std::array<TFloat, 3> array;

    const TFloat& x = array[0];
    const TFloat& y = array[1];
    const TFloat& z = array[2];
};

int main()
{
    Vector<float, 3> myArr = {1,2,3};
    assert((myArr.x + myArr.y) == 3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely a viable solution. However this does require double as much memory which I'm not comfortable with. I'm very curious about the approach you were suggesting with macros.

Comment: @LennyWhite I would not encourage macros, mixing templates and macros is going to make code difficult to read and debug, if you want to avoid the space overhead of the 3 references, you can compromise and define an `operator[]`.

Comment: @LennyWhite If you are adamant to save the ~24bytes for the three references, you could to [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/YWvY5j), but I don't think it is worth the added complexity.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll do what you suggested and just do away with using letters. There doesn't seem to be a good solution to the problem in C++ without space overhead or using dangerious practices.

Comment: @LennyWhite, it's only because you can't overload the "." operator, this restriction may be lifted soon: [may be coming soon](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4477.pdf).

Comment: That's sweet! Hope it does come to C++ soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228281/discussion-between-m-a-and-lenny-white).